# Установить атрибут "disabled" у select. Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Задача: установить выборочно атрибут  `disabled`. Перебирал несколько вариантов, не работает ни один. Также пытался изменить атрибут не функции. Тоже ничего не работает.

```
    $('.options_2').each(function(indx){

        optionBlock =  $(this).data('block');

        var optionBlockArr = optionBlock.split('_');

        if( !activBlocsArray.includes( optionBlockArr[1] ) ){

           // $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled" );
           // $(this).prop('disabled', true);
           // $(this).disabled = true;  
        }        
    });    


    //  $('.options_2').attr('disabled','disabled');
    //  $('.options_2').prop("disabled", true);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let select = $('.test');
$(select[0][1]).attr('disabled',true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="test">
  <option>Test 1</option>
  <option>Test 2</option>
  <option>Test 3</option>  
  <option>Test 4</option>
<select>
```

Comment: attr() давно не используется, используйте prop()

Comment: @DaemonHK, киньте ссылкой, что метод устаревший)

Comment: упс... извиняюсь... странно, видимо я с чем-то другим перепутал, но очень сильно похожим